# Rxjava pagination recursion - RxJava

Tags: android, recursion, retrofit2, rx-java2, rx-android

I'm working with retrofit and rxjava2. I have a problem, which is when I will open the application for the first time or open a new activity I have to retrieve data from the server using limits and offsets. And then the data is stored back into the local database (realm database). API service interface like this :

```
@GET(ApiUri.GET_LIST_CITY)
fun getlistOfCityWithOutParameter(
        @Query("limit") limit: Int,
        @Query("offset") offset: Int
): Observable<ResponseDataList<ResponseDataCityWithoutParameter>>
```

ResponseDataList like this :

```
class ResponseDataList<T> : BaseResponse() {
    @SerializedName("results")
    @Expose
    var result: MutableList<T>? = null
}
```

and BaseResponse () functions to implement the response of the REST server in terms of displaying data. like this :

```
open class BaseResponse {
    @SerializedName("status")
    var status: Int = 0
    @SerializedName("code")
    var code: Int = 0
    @SerializedName("message")
    var message: String? = null
    @SerializedName("generated")
    var generated: String? = null
    @SerializedName("serverTime")
    var serverTime: String? = null
    @SerializedName("totaldata")
    var totaldata: Int = 0
    @SerializedName("totalresult")
    var totalresult: Int = 0
}
```

and I ask how to handle the pagination API using rxjava to make calls until all data is retrieved.

Comment: Could you upload the structure of `ResponseDataList`? There should be a flag for when there is no more data to fetch.

Comment: ok bro I have uploaded the ResponseDataList structure at the top (updating the question) @CoderSpinoza